# C: printf non printing \n

Tags: c, sockets, newline, printf

In C, I ask the server to print the content of any messages that it receives. All messages follow the format: "Message: /counter/".

```
while (1){
            length = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    /*      receive from client */
            lenstr = recv(newfd, buff, 20000, 0);
            if (lenstr == -1){
                perror("recv(): ");
                exit(1);
            }
            buff[lenstr] = '\0';
            printf("Received: %s \n", buff);
    /*        send back to client*/
            if (send(newfd, buff, lenstr, 0) < 0){
                perror("send(): ");
                exit(-1);
            }
```

When I run the server, messages appear one after the other, without going to the new line. What am I missing here? (connection is TCP here)
Thanks.

Comment: If this is TCP, perhaps one recv() calls reads many lines sent from the client. TCP is just a stream of bytes, it doesn't slice the data up for you in messages or packets, that's up to you to do however you need it.

Comment: Oh I see. So this newline appears at the end of my possibly full buffer, right?

Comment: Yes, your buffer will contain however much data that was available when you call recv(), that data could be data from many send() calls (or partial data from a send() call)

Comment: How do I close this question?

Comment: Ask nos to make his comment a question and accept it. Else you can delete your question.

Comment: Or post the solution by your own and accept your answer ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ )

Answer (score 2):

The data it receives from the socket may contain zeroes or control characters. These should not be printed.

Try using the following function to dump received data into `stdout`. It replaces all non-printable characters with a dot:

```
void dump_buf(char const* buf, size_t buf_len) {
    char const* buf_end = buf + buf_len;
    while(buf != buf_end) {
        char c = *buf++;
        putchar(isprint(c) ? c : '.');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

// ...

lenstr = recv(newfd, buff, 20000, 0);
if (lenstr == -1) {
    perror("recv(): ");
    exit(1);
}
dump_buf(buff, lenstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP doesn't have "messages", it handles continuous byte streams in both directions. You are just reading whatever is less between the received data up to that instant and your 2000. Perhaps you really want [Stream Control Transmission Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol)? Or mark message ends in some way (perhaps by '\n'), and read character by character? Or just read the length of a single message (if they are fixed length, that is)?